# Scripting a txt file that asks you what you want in the file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a little script that will ask for the ip of the user and then automatically add and save to a text file. I got something liek this at the moment but its not working out.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is your IP?

"" >> ip.txt
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

For [prompting user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_02) you should use `read` keyword:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter IP and press [ENTER]:"
read ip
echo "$ip" > ip.txt
```

In the example above I used the > operator to write to a file, this means the file will be overwritten the next time you run this script. Use >> if you want to append the ip address to the file. (this would mean you get multiple ip's in the file if you run the script a few times instead of the last one)

Comment: can use `read -p "Enter IP and press [ENTER]:" ip` as well :)